# Get property name, need to retrieve only certain columns

Tags: c#, reflection, properties

**Answer Summary:**

Solved this problem using Jon Skeet's answer below. Here is the finished code

```
    public static CSVData CreateCSVData(List<RegDataDisplay> rList, 
                                                         string[] selectors)
    {
        CSVData csv = new CSVData(); // Create the CSVData object
        foreach(string selector in selectors)
        {
            // Get the PropertyInfo for the property whose name
            // is the value of selector
            var property = typeof(RegDataDisplay).GetProperty(selector); 

            // Use LINQ to get a list of the values for the specified property
            // of each RegDataDisplay object in the supplied list.
            var values = rList.Select(row => property.GetValue(row, null)
                              .ToString());

            // Create a new list with the property name to use as a header
            List<string> templs = new List<string>(){selector};

            // Add the returned values after the header 
            templs.AddRange(values);

            // Add this list as a column for the CSVData object.
            csv.Columns.Add(templs);
        }
        return csv;
    }
```

**Question**

I am building my SQL query dynamically from user input, and then exporting the results to a CSV file. I have a class called RegDataDisplay which has a property for each of the possible columns returned by my query. I can tell what columns are being selected but in my CSV creator I need to be able to only output those specific columns.

In the example below, all of the data I have retrieved is in rList, and the names of the properties I need are in selectors. So I want to iterate through the list and then add only the properties I need to my CSV data.

```
public static CSVData CreateCSVData(List<RegDataDisplay> rList, string[] selectors)
{ 
    CSVData csv = new CSVData();
    for(int i = 0; i < selectors.Length; i++)
    {
        csv.Columns.Add(new List<string>(){selectors[i]});
    }

    // So now I have the headers for the CSV columns, 
    // I need the specific properties only which is where I'm stuck

    for(int i = 0; i < selectors.Length; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < rList.Count; j++)
        {
            // If it was javascript I would do something like this 

            csv.Columns[i].Add(rList[j][selectors[i]]);

        } 
    }
}
```

Thanks

EDIT: On the right track now but I'm coming up against an error "Object does not match target type".

```
    public static CSVData CreateCSVData()
    {
        // I've created a test method with test data

        string[] selectors = new string[] { "Firstname", "Lastname" };
        List<RegDataDisplay> rList = new List<RegDataDisplay>();
        RegDataDisplay rd = new RegDataDisplay();
        rd.Firstname = "first";
        rd.Lastname = "last";
        rList.Add(rd);

        CSVData csv = new CSVData();
        foreach(string selector in selectors)
        {
            var property = typeof(RegDataDisplay).GetProperty(selector);
            var values = rList.Select(row => property.GetValue(rList, null).ToString())
                              .ToList(); // Error throws here
            csv.Columns.Add(values);
        }
        return csv;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're on .NET 3.5 or higher, it sounds like you may want something like:

```
public static CSVData CreateCSVData(List<RegDataDisplay> rList,
                                    string[] selectors)
{ 
    CSVData csv = new CSVData();
    foreach (string selector in selectors)
    {
        var prop = typeof(RegDataDisplay).GetProperty(selector);
        var values = rList.Select(row => (string) prop.GetValue(row, null))
                          .ToList();
        csv.Columns.Add(values);
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks good but I can't get it to work. If I step through the code, and look at the values variable. It has a results view which when expanded says "Object does not match target type". I changed the foreach to a for loop and then used "string s = (string)property.GetValue(rlist[0],null)" and that got the value for the first row fine. But this way I'll have to put it in to two loops again and I really liked your single loop.

Comment: @JamesHay: Are some of your properties not actually strings then? Okay, will edit.

Comment: I've edited my question to show the recent test method I'm trying. All the properties are strings.

Comment: @JamesHay: Doh - I had a typo. You should be calling `prop.GetValue(row, null)`, not `prop.GetValue(rList, null)`. Sorry about that.

Comment: Ah got it, just one more thing, is there a way I can append a header value so that the first value of each column is like "Firstname","Lastname" etc. I can do this manually but I'm pretty sure something you come up with will be like 1000 lines less code than mine.

Comment: @JamesHay: Would the first value be the `selector` itself then? The simplest way is probably `values.Insert(0, selector)` - horribly inefficient, admittedly...

Comment: Yeah I actually managed it quite easily, it's in my answer summary. I'm guessing mine would be far more memory hungry but faster(?). In either case the memory usage or performance speed should be negligible  for a max of about 250 rows and max of 25 columns per row.

Comment: @JamesHay: On yours, you can get rid of the `ToList` call, at which point it'll be more efficient than mine - just a little longer :)